# Setting column names of dataset with contents of list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, names, col

I read a table with data `TestTR` and one list with the corresponding column names `Headrs`. Now I want to set the column names of `TestTR` with the contents of `Headrs`:

```
TestTR:
 V1  V2  V3
 2   20   200
 1   10   100
 3   30   300

 Headrs: 
 Name1  Name2   Name3
```

This is what it should look like:

```
 Name1  Name2   Name3
 2   20   200
 1   10   100
 3   30   300
```

This is my code:

```
TestTR <- read.table(file="C:/Users/Sabine/Downloads/UCI_HAR_Dataset/mini_tr.txt", nrows=2)  
Headrs <- read.table(file="C:/Users/Sabine/Downloads/UCI_HAR_Dataset/features.txt", nrows=3)

 colnames(TestTR) <- Headrs

  print (class(Headrs)) #  gives me    "data.frame"
  print (dim(Headrs))   #  gives me     3   2
  print (Headrs)
   V1                V2
   1  1 tBodyAcc-mean()-X
   2  2 tBodyAcc-mean()-Y
   3  3 tBodyAcc-mean()-Z
```

It looks like the above (actually the names are not `name1`, `Name2`, `Name3`--I simplified here).

Comment: you can do this : `colnames(TestTR)<-paste("Name",1:3)`

Comment: Headrs is not a list, you can try this: `colnames(TestTR)<-colnames(Headrs)`

Comment: And what's inside `Headrs`? It should have two rows (you are reading 2 rows and the `dim()` show that also) but you are giving us only one.

Comment: $V2
[1] tBodyAcc-mean()-X tBodyAcc-mean()-Y tBodyAcc-mean()-Z
3 Levels: tBodyAcc-mean()-X ... tBodyAcc-mean()-Z       it looks like the above. ( actually the names are not name 1, Name2, Name3 - I simplified here)

Comment: What is `Headrs`? Could you please show an example? If headers is a data.frame `colnames(TestTR)<-colnames(Headrs)` should work

Comment: V1                V2
1  1 tBodyAcc-mean()-X
2  2 tBodyAcc-mean()-Y
3  3 tBodyAcc-mean()-Z       it looks like the above. ( actually the names are not name 1, Name2, Name3 - I simplified here)

Comment: `colnames(TestTR) <- Headrs$V2`

Comment: `colnames(TestTR)=list(Headrs$V2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
colnames(TestTR) <- c(names(Headrs))
```

Comment: sorry, nothing works. Headrs[2] is a list where the entries ( not the Headers) should become the Headers of TestTR